# Determine total size of static variables of class?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, static, sizeof

In C++, I can determine the size of a class object using `sizeof(my_class)`.

However, there seems to be no equivalent operator for the static part of a class.

Is there something like `sizeof(static my_class)` in C++?

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: There's no reflection in C++ so you may have to call this yourself, `sizeof(static_a) + sizeof(static_b) + ...`. If any of these are pointers to something allocated your estimates will be *way* off though.

Comment: `sizeof(my_class)` will also include the size of the vtable pointer.

Comment: Don't forget about padding. `sizeof(my_class)` might not be the size of every variable in the class.

Comment: Good points, I removed the statement about the size of the class object being equal to the sum of the non-static member variables.

Comment: @Barmar mainly for diagnostic reasons as I'm working with very tight memory constraints. I can get that information in other ways, though.

Comment: I’m not sure, but I think a class’s static variables might be guaranteed contiguous by some compilers (not by the language itself, though, I’m almost certain). In that case you can do pointer arithmetic (again, the language says that that’s UB but the compiler might be more generous) to get the size.

Comment: @DanielH Pointer arithmetic on what? The static variables aren't located anywhere near the objects.

Comment: @tadman That's probably the best estimate, although it won't include padding between the variables, just like adding the sizes of regular members isn't the same as the size of the class.

Comment: @Barmar The first and last static variable declared. It is definitely not a preferred method if the information’s available some other way, but I expect `(sizeof(C::last_static) + (static_cast<char*>(&C::last_static) - static_cast<char*>(&C::first_static))` would work on at least several platforms.

Comment: @DanielH Yes, that looks like it could be right. Post it as an answer, with an appropriate caveat that it's implementation-dependent.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, it's going to be a spitball estimate at best.

Comment: @Barmar Since iFreilicht can get the information in other ways, I am fairly sure those other ways are better. Especially because I don’t know for sure about any compilers making the guarantees I mentioned; I just think I heard about them somewhere. I think it’s at most a suggestion for where to start looking, than an actual answer.

Comment: @DanielH - this most certainly wont' work on most modern compilers unless all variables end up in the same _section_. Since the section used depends on whether the data is `const`, is zero-initialized, has a compile-time vs runtime initializer, the "size" of the data, and more it is very likely that static variables will end up in a variety of sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't find a legal or portable<sup>1</sup> way to do this in standard C++, but you can certainly use platform-specific tools to examine the binary to get an estimate of the size of global data.

On Unix platforms you can use one of a variety of ELF-format reading tools to dump the symbol table along with sizes. For example, something like:

```
nm --demangle --print-size a.out | egrep -i ' [bdgsr] '
```

Will dump the size (as the second field in the output) of all the global data in the `.bss`, `.data`, `.rodata` and related sections<sup>2</sup>.

The `--demangle` argument gives you human-readable names from the C++ mangled names. The `egrep` at the end of the pipeline restricts the symbols to the ones that are typically used for static variables (i.e., it omits the symbols for functions). Given the following class:

```
class Foo {

        static void StaticFunction();

        void MemberFunction();

        static int some_int_s;
        static long some_zero_long;
        static char some_char_array[];
        static const char *some_const_string;
};

int Foo::some_int_s = 5;
char Foo::some_char_array[42];
const char* Foo::some_const_string = "hello, world?";

void Foo::StaticFunction() {
}

void Foo::MemberFunction() {
        static double f = 0.5;
}
```

... and compiled with `g++`, the `nm` command given above outputs:

```
0000000000000000 0000000000000004 D Foo::some_int_s
0000000000000000 000000000000002a B Foo::some_char_array
0000000000000008 0000000000000008 D Foo::some_const_string
0000000000000010 0000000000000008 d Foo::MemberFunction()::f
```

The second column is the size of the global: 4 bytes for the `int`, 0x2a (42) bytes for the `char[]` and so on. Note that it includes function-local static variables as well, which is probably what you want since they take up size like anything else. You can use another `grep` to restrict to specific classes.

Note that `Foo::some_const_string` has size 8, despite having the value `hello, world?` which is 14 characters (including the terminating null). In fact, you'll find that any `const char *` or any static pointer at all will have size 8 on a 64-bit platform, since that is the size of the pointer itself. The actual data for the *string literal* (the characters `h,e,l,l,o,...`) are stored somewhere else and this size is not reported by `nm`. In general determining the size of string literals [is complex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28621984/149138) and may not have a straightforward answer (i.e,. several classes may share the same underlying literal data). You'll probably have to script something like `readelf` if you really want to include that in your accounting.

You might also try existing binary sizing utilities, such as [Bloaty McBloatface](https://github.com/google/bloaty), although a quick scan of the readme seems to indicate that it might simply give the same information as above (for example, it doesn't seem to handle the "string literal" issue).

---

<sup>1</sup> For example, [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45697799/determine-total-size-of-static-variables-of-class/46657567#comment78354515_45697799) mentions an approach of taking the difference of the "first" and "last" statics at runtime to estimate the size, but in addition to being *undefined behavior* it isn't likely to work in practice since global variables get spread across various sections in the binary, such as `.bss`, `.data`, `.rodata` and other variants of those, so a simply subtraction will almost certainly return the wrong result for many classes.

<sup>2</sup> In particular, when I say "related" I mean that it dumps the size of the "small" initialized and uninitialized sections in addition to the default ones.