# Having trouble checking whether template parameter is something you get when you pass a function's identifier

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, type-traits

I want to implement the following function:

```
template<typename Function, typename... Parameters>
inline void foo(
    const Function&   kernel_function,
    bar_t             bar
    Parameters...     parameters)

{
    static_assert(/* magic */,
        "You can only foo() a function, not values of any other type");
    / * etc. etc. */
}
```

and I need it to only be called with the identifiers of functions, or with pointers to functions: No lambads or methods or classes with `operator()` or `std::function`s. What should I replace `/* magic */` with? Just using `std::is_function` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: So you want the `static_assert` to fire only when `Function` is a function or a pointer to a function?

Comment: Googled "C++ type trait function pointer" and found: [SO: c++ - `std::enable_if` is function pointer - how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666218/stdenable-if-is-function-pointer-how). There are two answers which should solve your problem too (if I got it right).

Comment: What about non-capturing lambdas which are implicitly convertable to function pointers?

Comment: @Scheff: Thanks and sorry, I did some googling but not on those terms. will read that and delete / mark for closure if necessary.

Comment: @user1937198: I was describing what I'm passing in, in practice. If it's something that decays into a function pointer, then I'll be willing to take it obviously. If it doesn't then I want to detect it.

Comment: @Scheff: So, that's about function pointers, but if I pass a function, or a reference to a function, will I always get that? Or would I need to decay then use the trait at the linked-to question?

Comment: @einpoklum Hmm. Until now I considered functions and function pointers as equal (when passed) but this might be my C limited view onto this (not to mention function references). (I just was happy to contribute some helpful google search terms...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`std::enable\_if\` is function pointer - how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666218/stdenable-if-is-function-pointer-how)

Answer (score 1):

In [`<type_traits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) we have [`std::is_function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function) which returns `true` if you pass it an actual function and `false` with lambdas, classes with overloaded `operator()` and pointers to functions. We also have [`std::is_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer) and [`std::remove_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer) which can be used to check for and remove the pointer type from a function pointer to test the pointer with `std::is_function`.  Using those your assert would look like

```
static_assert(std::is_function<Function>::value || 
    (std::is_pointer<Function>::value &&
    std::is_function<std::remove_pointer<Function>::type>::value),
    "You can only foo() a function, not values of any other type");
```

Comment: Wouldn't I have issues with references-to-functions? No need to `std::decay` or something? Also your static assert would fire for a non-function; are you sure you got your boolean logic right?

Comment: @einpoklum Do you want to assert to fire the `Function` is a function/function pointer or not?  The text in the assert makes it seems like you only want it to fire if `Function` is not a function/function pointer.

Comment: I want to ensure that Function is a function or a function pointer.

Comment: OK.  So why is it a problem that the assert fires for a non function?

Comment: @einpoklum Now I understand.  I had a negation when I should not have.  Not sure why But for some reason I had it backwards.

Comment: The reason is that the foo() enqueues the function to be launched as a CUDA kernel. Actually, even just functions is not restrictive enough, but I can't check for the compiler-specific attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on @DietmarKuhl' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18667268/1593077) in the [sort-of-duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666218/stdenable-if-is-function-pointer-how):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<typename Fun>
struct is_function_ptr: std::integral_constant<bool,
    std::is_pointer<Fun>::value and
    std::is_function<typename std::remove_pointer<Fun>::type>::value> { };


template<typename Function, typename... Parameters>
inline void foo(
    const Function&   kernel_function,
    bar_t             bar
    Parameters...     parameters)
{
    static_assert(
        std::is_function<Function>::value or is_function_ptr<Function>::value,
        "You can only foo() a function, not values of any other type");

    / * etc. etc. */
}
```

Although, to be honest, I have not tested extensively.